# How to optimize my memory usage with sprites...between SpriteFrameCache and SpriteBatchNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have seen the usage of `plist` and `png` atlasses for the game i am developing. However I've notice a slight performance swiftness(speed up) keeping the 60 fps, and for a side note my app has not crash at the moment.

The thing is I noticed I have used `SpriteFrameCache` with `plist` to do `CCactions` and animations for my characters(sprites). However some of the characters ive been using `SpriteBatchnode`, but it was on accident, since I am relatively new to deep development of a game, I didnt notice this difference before, they both work, but I feel like both are the same, its just that one has an easier way of implementation than the other, i was thinking that perhaps it was developed in an earlier version....

so my question is. is there a difference between the two? will my game benefit for using `SpriteFrameCache` over `SpriteBatchNode`?

Thanks for the help.

FYI: this doesnt slow down my developing, its just a question because I know at the end when my game is finished maybe i would want to optimize performance for my game.

Answer (score 0):

Batch nodes draw all child sprites in one draw call.

Sprite frames hold a reference to a texture and define a region in the texture to draw from. The cache allows you to access sprite frames by name.

Both are different concepts, they are not replacements for each other. You can use sprite frames to create sprites or sprite frame animations. In addition to that sprite batching enables you to speed up rendering of two or more sprites using the same texture.

Note that if you use a batch node with only a single child sprite this will not be any different from rendering the sprite without the batch node, since both create a single draw call so there is no positive effect in using the batch node.

Comment: ahh so the batch node is not used for animations, the batch node it can be used to like have different objects around my background that dont much or at all. 

Thanks for the clarification.